# Why must this variable be outside of the scope of setInterval?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer, setinterval

I have a working countdown timer that currently requires the page to be reloaded once the time has been reached before it will count down to the next time.

I have attempted to move the code that determines how many seconds are remaining to inside the `setInterval` so that it doesn't require the page to be reload to determine this value, it would just do it when the counter is restarted after the time is reached.

This didn't work however and stops the timer counting down after displaying the time remaining after page reload.

I have one setInterval that runs the timer. When the time reaches 0 it clears itself and runs the announement setInterval. The announcement setInterval runs for a few seconds before clearing itself and starting the timer setInterval.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
            // define times to countdown to and the time now
            $time1  = strtotime(gmdate("02:00:00"));
            $time2  = strtotime(gmdate("08:00:00"));
            $time3  = strtotime(gmdate("12:56:00"));
            $time4  = strtotime(gmdate("20:00:00"));
            $timeNow = strtotime("now");

?>


<script type="text/javascript">
            // parse the PHP variables to javascript (because I don't know how to do equivalent in js yet)
            var time1 = parseInt("<?php echo $time1;?>");
            var time2 = parseInt("<?php echo $time2;?>");
            var time3 = parseInt("<?php echo $time3;?>");
            var time4 = parseInt("<?php echo $time4;?>");
            var timeNow = parseInt("<?php echo $timeNow;?>");

            // difference in seconds between highest PM time and lowest AM time
            var highLowDif = 21600;

            // create an array to store times in
            var timeInSeconds = [ time1, time2, time3, time4 ];

            // initiate the target hour variable
            var targetHour = 0;

            // loop through each element and retrieve the next time to countdown to
                for(var i = 0; i < timeInSeconds.length; i++) {

                        // if this time is greater than the current time assign it to targetHour variables and break out of
                        // the loop because we only want the next highest
                        if(timeInSeconds[i] > timeNow) { 

                            targetHour = timeInSeconds[i]; 
                            break; 
                        }
                        // If there is no higher time than get the next lowest time 
                        var temp = timeInSeconds[i];
                        if(timeInSeconds[i] > temp){
                            temp = TimeInSeconds[i];
                        }
                }
                // If no higher time could be found then its really late at night and the next time is in the am
                if(targetHour == 0){

                    // get difference between time now and the earliest am time
                    var highDif = timeNow - temp;

                    // to count down from late pm to early am we find out how many seconds it is between now and the next 
                    // time, subtract the difference from this number and then add the remainder to the time now
                    targetHour = timeNow + (highLowDif - highDif);
                }

                // get the difference between the next time and the time now to work out how long there is to go in seconds
                var dif = targetHour - timeNow;

            // run the timer
            var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

            function timer()
            {



                // if we reach the target time then restart the timer for the next time we want to count down to
                if(dif == 0){
                    clearInterval(counter);
                    var announce = setInterval(announcement, 1000);
                }else{

                    // work out how many hours, minutes and seconds there are
                    var dh1 = Math.floor(dif/3600) % 24;
                    var dm1 = Math.floor(dif/60) % 60;
                    var ds1 = dif % 60; 

                    // countdown one second
                    dif=dif-1;
                    // show current time left on the countdown timer
                    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML="<span id=\"countdown\">"+dh1+"h "+dm1+"m "+ds1+"s</span>";
                }
            }

    // How long the announcement will last when time is reached in seconds
    var announceTime = 5;

    function announcement()
    {
        if(announceTime == 0){
            clearInterval(announce);
            counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
        }else{
            announceTime = announceTime - 1;
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML="Time reached, waiting"+announceTime+" seconds before counting down to next time.";
        }   
    }
</script>
```

So how can I rearrange the code so that it calculates time remaining inside the counter setInterval?

edit@ [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KTzn6/3/)

Comment: Are you sure you want `setInterval`? Very few cases actually need it. Is it possible you wanted `setTimeout` instead?

Comment: please create demo in jsfiddle.net that both replicates problem and gives better overview of expected behavior

Comment: @Sukima With a counter, you'll need `setInterval`. Using `setTimeout` will create a lag-behind, because the timer usually starts after the code is executed.

Comment: @charlietfl I tried but because I use PHP JSFiddle doesnt like it :(

Comment: well you would obviously replace php code with real output, no diffferent than what you see in browser source

Comment: @crm: Can you not hardcode the values for `time1/time2...` variables for the jsfiddle demo? In general your javascript should be testable without the dependency of PHP that is a bit to tightly coupled.

Comment: I think you are over thinking it. Pass the end time to the client, calculate the difference between current time and end time.

Comment: heres jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KTzn6/2/

Comment: @epascarello I dont follow, how does that relate to my issue with the setinterval?